# How to permanently remove a UNC path from $env:PSModulePath for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Where I work, users have their folders redirected to a UNC path to save data. This seems to have affected my PowerShell because every time I start up powershell, it attempts to load modules from the UNC path and it takes a long time. This also affects how I use cmdlets because it tries to search the UNC path for cmdlet context.

When I look at the output of `$env:PSModulePath` I can see the UNC directory. But it doesn't show up in System's Environment Variables dialog editor.

How can I get rid of this so that Powershell doesn't keep looking for module support from the UNC directory? I understand that I can edit an existing sessions $env:PSModulePath, but I want it gone forever.

Comment: Check `'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\', 'HKCU:\Environment\' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Item "$_").GetValue('PSModulePath')}`.

Comment: The UNC path doesn't show up here in this registry key.

Comment: Check **1.** `dir env:\ | Where-Object Value -Match ([regex]::Escape( "\\" ))` and **2.** `$profile | gm -type noteproperty | % { $_.Name; sls -Path $profile.$($_.Name) -Pattern $([regex]::Escape( '\\'))}` if the UNC path is present there.

Comment: Prior the above: check whether the described behaviour occurs if you omit profiles running `powershell -noprofile`?

Comment: I still get the behavior running powershell.exe -noprofile. I get 3 hits from running the script `dir env:\ | Where-Object Value -Match ([regex]::Escape( "\\" ))`. The UNC path shows up in the following names: `HOMESHARE` `LOGONSERVER` `PSModulePath`

The 2nd script returns errors because it doesn't find a profile.ps1 file

Comment: Presence of the `LogonServer` environment variable indicates that you are in a _domain_ environment. Ask your domain admin…

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft documentation page [about_PSModulePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7.1#powershell-psmodulepath-construction) explains it. By default, PowerShell builds the `$env:PSModulePath` value by concatenating:

- The user's "Documents" folder, likely the UNC path you are mentioning.
- The contents of the `PSModulePath` system environment variable.

You can find out the path of the "Documents" folder as follows:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
```

If you define a user-level environment variable `PSModulePath` in addition to the system environment variable `PSModulePath`, it will replace your "Documents" folder in `$env:PSModulePath`, which won't contain the UNC path anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently change the `PSModulePath` environment variable, you can use the .NET method `SetEnvironmentVariable` on the `System.Environment` class.

Example:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Some_Path", "Machine")`

**Keep in mind**, this will overwrite what you had before on this variable. So make sure before you run the method as the `PSModulePath` will certainly have paths that you might need.

Also, if your company is using GPOs to set the `PSModulePath` variable, then the only way to remove the UNC path is to talk to your administrator that handles that.

Comment: The UNC path still remains after setting the path with the .NET method. It does seem that a GPO is setting this after some time, so my goal is to just run a powershell script to find this in the registry and remove it whenever GPO sets it again.

Comment: The .NET method will only affect future power shell sessions. So you’d have to open a new session to power shell to see the changes. I would check with your company to see if this is allowed. Circumventing GPO might bring consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not shown in your system variables GUI. You should be able to remove it with something along these lines:

```
$yourvalueyouwanttodelete = 'somepath'
$oldval = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath")
$arr_oldval = $oldval -split ";"
$arr_newval = $arr_oldval | ? {$_ -ne $yourvalueyouwanttodelete}
$newval = $arr_newval -join ";"
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $newval)
```

Comment: Restarting the Powershell session restores the UNC path to $env:PSModulePath

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this was to set the Module Path in the All users profile

For me $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts returned:
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1
I created that file and added the following:

```
$ModulePath = "c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $ModulePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after removing PowerShell 7 from my device. What appears to be happening is that the PSModulePath variable to My Documents is removed from the environment variables under Advanced System Settings. Powershell then uses the UNC path, which is configured by group policy.

The solution, that worked for me was to add a new Environment Variable called PSModulePath with the value of C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\Documents. Now powershell has a place to look for those PS Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `PSModulePath` user environment variable didn't prevent Powershell from automagically adding `%userprofile%\Documents` to the PSModulePath variable at the start of every session. I was only able to remove my UNC Documents path from the `PSModulePath` environment variable  by creating a profile file and manually overwriting the `PSModulePath` environment variable there.

1. Output `$profile` and create the .ps1 file at that location if it doesn't exist
2. Add a line to set the PSModulePath environment variable manually to the correct list of paths, excluding any offending UNC paths (ex: `$Env:PSModulePath = 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;...'`)